# webview background-color doesn't seem to expand to cover entire view

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have a webview that is picking up the background color in a css:

```
body {
  color: var(--vscode-editor-foreground);
  background-color: var(--vscode-editor-background);
}
```

Unfortunately, for "short" web pages, it's not expanding to cover the entire view port.

[image: webview with white area at bottom of display area]

Is there something I can do to the html I'm including in the webview to expand it to fill the space? This obviously only happens on darker themes and light themes work fine - and doesn't happen with larger html files.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was just another minor stylesheet issue:

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

That fixed it right up. Thank you Mosh Feu for the answer.